# good/simple example asp:gridview describing all its functionalities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a temporary datatable,

```
 private DataTable getmyDatatable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;
        dc = new DataColumn("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc = new DataColumn("Age");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc = new DataColumn("Address");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc = new DataColumn("Phone");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        //dc = new DataColumn("Sex");
        //dt.Columns.Add(dc);

        dt.Rows.Add("bala", "24", "cbe","999444444");
        dt.Rows.Add("chendur", "23", "bangalore","9999999999");
        dt.Rows.Add("chchandru", "22", "chennai","888888888");

        return dt;
    }
```

Now i want this datatable to bind it to a gridview and work out row editing,row deleting,row updating, new row add etc... As i am a beginner refer me good/simple example asp:gridview describing all its functionalities? Any suggestion..

Comment: In my experience, GridView is a world of pain. You'll inextricably 'bind' your data to the HTML. If I was you, I'd focus on creating an ordinary table to present your data, and add any functionality you need from the grid view manually. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asp.net QuickStart for GridView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)s is one option.